# Does anyone know how to use an iOS modal page like this in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, react-native

[image]

I did this on react native with stack navigator, but I have no idea how to do this on flutter.

Comment: I think this is your answer [Cupertino date picker](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-cupertino-date-picker/)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this type of design by using [flutter_rounded_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker)
the code for that is

```
CupertinoRoundedDatePicker.show(
context,
fontFamily: "Mali",
textColor: Colors.white,
background: Colors.red[300],
borderRadius: 16,
initialDatePickerMode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
onDateTimeChanged: (newDateTime) {
//
},
);
```

[image]

check out the example